# Is there a better way of modifying arrays from within a function in C?

Tags: c, arduino, esp32

I am trying to create a formatted string , however I do not know why I cannot print global array which I have modified inside the function.Also the strange behavior is that I cannot access only a specific global array (rand_session_key) rest of the other global arrays are behaving as normal(similar operations are being done on them except their size varies) and I can access their value properly. This code is run on an esp32 (DOIT Dev Kit V1) (with Arduino-Core) , when I run this program on my computer (modifying a few functions etc.) the result is what I expect , I think I am overlapping the characters in the memory or accessing it the wrong way , but had it been the case I would not have yielded the expected output on my computer.

I tried to modify my program and made it more verbose. Also I ran the same code (with some obvious modifications to make it run on my computer) , and the result is good as expected.

```
char persistent_peripheral_id[] = "FRUCTOSE96";
char rand_session_iden[7] = {'\0'};
char rand_session_key[17] = {'\0'};
char rand_session_channel[3] = {'\0'};

char *generate_random_session_identifier(char *rand_session_iden_local)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int counter = 0;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
        *(rand_session_iden_local + counter) = (random(10) % ('~' - ' ')) + 'k';
    rand_session_iden_local[counter] = '\0';
    printf("Identifier : %s\n", rand_session_iden); //acessing global defintion of array everything is good until here
    return &rand_session_iden_local[0];
}

char *generate_random_session_key(char *rand_session_key_local)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int counter = 0;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 16; counter++)
        *(rand_session_key_local + counter) = (random(10) % ('~' - ' ')) + 'b';
    rand_session_key_local[counter] = '\0';
    printf("Key : %s\n", rand_session_key);//acessing global defintion of array everything is good until here
    return &rand_session_key_local[0];
}

char *generate_random_session_channel(char *rand_session_channel_local)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int channel_value = random(100);
    sprintf(rand_session_channel_local, "%03ld", channel_value);
    printf("Channel : %s\n", rand_session_channel);//acessing global defintion of array everything is good until here
    return &rand_session_channel_local[0];
}

void begin_exchange_package()
{
    //If this does not works here (observe rand_session_key) , it will not work for sprintf also ??
    printf("\n %s-%s-%s-%s \n", (char *)persistent_peripheral_id,
           generate_random_session_identifier(rand_session_iden),
           generate_random_session_key(rand_session_key),
           generate_random_session_channel(rand_session_channel));

    //Notice it prints here ????
    printf("\n %s \n",generate_random_session_key(rand_session_key));
    Serial.println("Done");


    //sprintf((char *)plain_text_package, "{\"p\":\"%s\",\"r\":\"%s\",\"k\":\"%s\",\"c\":\"%s\"}", (char *)persistent_peripheral_id,(char *)rand_session_iden, (char *)rand_session_key , (char *)rand_session_channel);

}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    begin_exchange_package();
}

void loop()
{
}
```

The Output is 
FRUCTOSE96-tnltkp--094
Where I expected all the 4 arrays to be printed ?? but it does print separately , is my array being terminated in the wrong way ?? also the logic to assign a random character will always yield a printable ASCII Character (I learned this from a forum on esp32's website)

Comment: How about a [mcve]?

Comment: Hello , Thanks for your suggestion , I removed the unused variables and imports , I think this is the smallest I could make , also I thought in case if someone wants to run this code they can right away without making any changes to it , I have removed anything platform / library dependent to make it easy , its just plain C. Thanks

Comment: Note that expressions of the form `&pointer[0]` are 100% equivalent to the simpler form `pointer`.  The latter is more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning , I might have made those changes in order to make it more verbose(or debugging) , I recently learned pointers and the concept of "Pointer Decays" , I will remember John's Comments and put it under "Good Practices " when I code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code ...

> ```
>     sprintf(rand_session_channel_local, "%03ld", channel_value);
> ```

... requires `rand_session_channel_local` to point to an array of at least *four* characters, because at will print at least three digits plus a string terminator.  The array into which it points, `rand_session_channel`, is only three characters long.  The resulting behavior is undefined.

The observed manifestation of the UB is consistent with the global arrays being laid out in memory such that `rand_session_key` immediately follows `rand_session_channel`, such that overflowing the latter means that the string terminator is written to position 0 of the former, making it an empty string.  Note, however, that you cannot rely on predicting manifestations of UB, nor is it generally of much use to analyze them.  Instead, avoid exercising UB.

It's unclear what `random` function you are using, since the C standard library's does not take an argument, but if the argument to yours specifies an *exclusive* upper bound then you could just change the `sprintf` format to `"%02ld"`.  Alternatively, increase the size of `rand_session_channel` to at least 4.

Comment: It was indeed the undefined behavior , increasing the size to 4 for rand_session_channel_local did yield me the expected output. However It would be very interesting to understand why such a behavior was not observed on my computer ? and why on the esp32 ?